# Terraform only resolve TF_VAR values from stored environment variables in windows

Tags: windows, terraform

I am trying to use env variables in terraform using "TF_VAR_". It only works for permanently set environment variables. When I try to set session-specific env variables, it is not working

env: Windows 10
terminal: command line

scripts:

```
set TF_VAR_env_name = "dev"
set TF_VAR_region = "eu-west-2"
set TF_VAR_role_arn = "arn:aws:I am::....."
```

Please I need help to provide this kind of session-specific variable to run terraform. Thanks.

Comment: What shell are you using? Powershell or cmd?

Comment: @Paolo I used both. but same result

Comment: So you used the code you showed in both cmd and powershell?

Comment: @Paolo no this is just a  .bat file I run this bat file using cmd and then I run terraform plan. But It didn't resolve these values. I try to set env variables in Powershel as well and try to use them. But same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a `cmd` terminal, you would have to use:

```
set TF_VAR_env_name=dev
set TF_VAR_region=eu-west-2
set TF_VAR_role_arn=arn:aws:...
```

to set these environment variables.